# Объектная модель Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-basic, vbscript

Искал в Google , в Google.Dev , не нашёл . Нужно получить объектную модель GoogleChrome в VBScript . 
Для InternetExplorer это делается с помощью команды

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Как провернуть то же самое с Chrome и остаться в живых ? И с помощью каких объектов можно убрать в открывшемся окне Chrome статус бар , юрл бар и тд...

В IE это убирается с помощью

```
ie.menubar=0
ie.toolbar=0
ie.addressbar=0
ie.statusbar=0
```

Ищу аналог этих функций для Chrome

Comment: А на чем основано Ваше предположение, что Chrome вообще предоставляет какой-либо COM-интерфейс?

Comment: решил спросить , есть ли он вообще . Из ответа я так понял что его нет . Правильно я думаю ?

Comment: Ну, я не могу сказать наверняка, но насколько я знаю, действительно нет.

Comment: @Yaant , хоть в чём то IE лучший